# Android: Double Value dissappears inside textbox

Tags: java, android, textview, double

A simple countdowntimer that updates the value of a double variable and then display the value onto the end of a textbox. I have done this with integers and it works fine, however when I use a double value it just simply disappears from the end of the textbox. Is there a reason for this occurance?

Code used:

```
PSICount = new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer2.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if(alti >= 33000){
                Random r = new Random();
                double Low = 0.2 ;
                double High = 0.5;
                double randomValue = Low + (High - Low) * r.nextDouble();
                pressure = pressure - randomValue;
                pressureT.setText("Pressure: "+ pressure + " PSI");

            }
            PSICount.start();
        }
    };
    PSICount.start();
```

This is the timer and it triggers every 5 seconds if the value of another variable is above 33000. As soon as that variable reaches 33000, the textbox (which has a placeholder value of 10.0 at the end) does not display any value at the end. Do I need to do something to use doubles with textViews?

Thank you

My entire Class:

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class flight_engineer extends AppCompatActivity {

int fuel = 100;
int alti = 10000;
int speed = 50;
double over_heat = 600;
double pressure = 10.0;

CountDownTimer fuelCount;
CountDownTimer PSICount;
CountDownTimer spike;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flight_engineer);

    //sets screen orientation on created
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Stencil WW.ttf");

    final TextView fuelT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fuelText);
    final TextView pressureT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.presText);
    final TextView altitudeT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.altText);
    final TextView speedT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.speedText);
    final TextView over_heatingT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.heatText);
    final TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoText);
    final TextView timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    final TextView timer2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer2);

    fuelT.setTypeface (typeface);
    pressureT.setTypeface (typeface);
    altitudeT.setTypeface (typeface);
    speedT.setTypeface (typeface);
    over_heatingT.setTypeface (typeface);
    info.setTypeface(typeface);

    fuelT.setText("Fuel: "+fuel);
    pressureT.setText("Pressure: "+ pressure+ " PSI");
    altitudeT.setText("Altitude: "+alti+" ft");
    speedT.setText("Speed: "+speed+" MPH");
    over_heatingT.setText("System Heat: "+over_heat+" °C");

    Button speedPlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speedPlus);

    speedPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });


    fuelCount = new CountDownTimer(2000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            fuelCount.start();
            fuel--;
            fuelT.setText("Fuel: "+fuel);
            over_heat=over_heat + 4;
            fuelT.setText("Fuel: "+fuel);
            over_heatingT.setText("System Heat: "+over_heat+" °C");

            Random r = new Random();
            int Low = 443;
            int High = 872;
            int Result = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
            alti = alti + Result;
            altitudeT.setText("Altitude: "+alti+" ft");



        }
    };
    fuelCount.start();

    PSICount = new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer2.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            if(alti >= 33000){
                Random r = new Random();
                double Low = 0.2 ;
                double High = 0.5;
                double randomValue = Low + (High - Low) * r.nextDouble();
                pressure = pressure - randomValue;
                pressureT.setText("Pressure: "+ pressure + " PSI");

            }
            PSICount.start();
        }
    };
    PSICount.start();

    spike = new CountDownTimer(30000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            spike.start();
            over_heat = over_heat + 50;
            over_heatingT.setText("System Heat: "+over_heat+" °C");

            alti = alti + 1000;
            altitudeT.setText("Altitude: "+alti+" ft");

            if(speed < 300 || speed > 300) {
                Random r = new Random();
                int Low = -50;
                int High = 50;
                int Result = r.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
                speed = speed + Result;
                speedT.setText("Speed: " + speed + " MPH");
            }

        }
    };
    spike.start();

}

}
```

Comment: whats the return type of 'pressure'

Comment: pressure is a double

Comment: Have you debug the code, i think 'alti' is not >= 30000
Thats why, if condition get false

Comment: Well when I run this I can see the value of alti and it does reach 33000 and as soon as it reaches that, the placeholder value disappears and is replaced with nothing.

Comment: It was doing this with another previous double value that I just changed to an integer to save time but now I am just curious to why this is happening.

Comment: If this is the condition than, i have to see the whole working flow of 'alti' parameter.  Update your code here, i will check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140118/discussion-between-kushal-and-george-brooks).

Comment: tried Double.toString (pressure)?

Comment: Already tried conversion, same result.